# Block certain URLs for security in android webview

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I am trying to intercept the url click in my webview. I want to block certain urls from getting launched when they are clicked in webview.

For that I am overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. But still what ever is return `true/false` that url is getting launched.

e.g if i want to block `http://www.xyz.com` I am able to get the url string and able to varify it with my black list urls but it is getting launched irrespective of return value.

I may be wrong at approach I need suggestion

Comment: Have you provided a `WebViewClient`? Also, why not use the `shouldInterceptRequest()`-method, which sounds more like what you want.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth :Thanks yes I have provided webview client will check on         shouldInterceptRequest() method

Comment: You can use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method and return true, get the URL will be loading, if it's in your black list, then load your own `warning view`

Comment: Thanks **All** : `shouldInterceptRequest()` method worked as well as `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` I did some parsing on received urls from above methods and it worked. :)

Comment: @dreamtale : Can you please explain this statement "You can use shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and return true, get the URL will be loading"

Comment: When implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, return true means you will process the URL by your application instead of default browser, as well you can get the URL.

Comment: can also be done by pattern matching , I did it once but dont remember rit now ...
does anybody know or has done this please let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
 @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url)
{
     if(url.equals("from your list")){
         //DO something
     }
    return true;
}
```

however i dont quite remeber the boolean value.just give it a try....

Comment: It blocks only webview in my app..but I want to block in all browser installed in my device.