# How to open urls in new screen for android webview and get back to previous page on back key press?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-browser

I am trying to learn and implement android Webview for my own understanding.

As a part of it I want my Webview to behave like android browser. So that every url can be launched in new screen.

e.g. if some url on page A is clicked then it should be opened in new screen and click on any url on this screen will launch the new screen and so on.

I want to navigate back to prev page on back key just like the default browser does.

I need suggestions about my approach if anybody has done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

back button to prev page is .goback() and

```
@Override   
public void onBackPressed(){
if(history is not null)
webview.goBack();
    else
     finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121273/1075066)
and for do something just use an intent with flag "start new activity" and action as action.view