# Is it possible to block a list of site in android browser?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block certain URLs for security in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121089/block-certain-urls-for-security-in-android-webview)

I want to block a list of urls in browser by programatically. Anyone has any idea ? Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ketu, do you want it to be part of your APK or you want it general? I mean from your APK some webview should restricted some URL's?

Comment: in that case Androids WebView class provides a method called shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept the loading of the requested URLs.
This gives us the ability to suppress loading of the given URL or handle a URL in the external browser for example. You can check above answer of above for the same.

Comment: but I dont know how to use it. Can you provide some code ? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for all browser installed in device ?