# Android WebView needs to launch specific URLs in separate browser

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I have made an app that uses a WebView to view a mobile website.  The mobile website displays a "back" button within the WebView for pages served by its web server, but certain pages display links that navigate to external websites.  I would like to display a "back" button on those pages to get back to the original web server, but if this is not possible I would like to launch these external sites in the standard browser in such a way that the user can still navigate the original site in the WebView using the "back" button the mobile site contains.

As it stands, my app cannot navigate back to the mobile site once a user clicks one of these "external" links because those sites do not display a back button to get back to the mobile app.

Comment: Can I use something like this to just check if the URL belongs to the domain of my mobile site and, if it doesn't, tell my app to load the external URL in the standard browser?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121089/block-certain-urls-for-security-in-android-webview/10121273#10121273

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for your WebView.

You can refer [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for the example for the same.

For example:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });

 webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com");
```

Comment: @gonzobrains if you implement WebViewClient, it will make navigation within your WebView instead of launching native browser for every link user clicks.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am trying to do.  I have a mobile site displaying within my app now, but I want it to launch the native browser when displaying "external" web pages that are not part of my mobile site.