# React Native in-app browser app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new to React Native, I need Your suggestions please. I am building a React Native in-app browser app to restrict browser visiting pages other than the once they are given permission to visit. I have plans of using **Linking** and **Webview** provided by React Native. Also, I want to implement it in a way that the user is not able to close the application without a password. Thanks.

Comment: did you able to develop one? If it's an open source, then please share it here.

Comment: Check this plugin https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you have the [`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest) method, which lets you decide which requests should be allowed and which should not. Attempts have been made to port this functionality to Android [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6478), but it seems unlikely to make it to the release version any time soon. Here are however two solutions: Set the current URL in your `state`. Then subscribe to the [`onLoadStart`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/webview.html#onloadstart) method and check the new URL there. If it does satisfy your needs, set it to the `state`, effectively continuing rendering (you might run into an infinite loop if you are not careful, maybe if the URL is the same as the one in the state, do nothing). Otherwise, replace the new URL with the old one, or call `goBack()`. The second option is to implement a custom WebView that extends the one of React Native and implements this functionality. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121273/2628463) for reference, and [this component](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android) to see an implementation reference of a custom WebView.